# MVC Webapp hide/show website tabs with Azure AD Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, user-roles

I have an MVC WebApp where I am successfully authenticating and pulling Azure AD Roles into my app. How can I show or hide navbar tabs like 'home' 'about' and so on  in my _Layout.cshtml file, based on that role?

I can authorize pages in the controller with `[Authorize(Roles = "")]` but I want to hide at the navbar level. What line(s) of code am I missing to make this dynammic?

Here is the code in my _Layout.cshtml file that I am looking to make this happen:

```
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("My Project", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MVC, you have the `User` object, which gives you the information about the logged user. Just use the `User.IsInRole(roleName)` method, it should work.

Example:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        @Html.ActionLink("My Project", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
            @if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                //Only the user with "Admin" role can see this
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            }
        </ul>
        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
    </div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Glad to help. Make sure to check the correct answer, so other people with the same issue can find this answer easier.